# Separate/unstack column into three separate columns when there are NA values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a column that looks like this

```
value 
Ford
Focus
2,300
Chevy
15
Toyota
245
Honda
Nissan
```

How would I get it to look like this? Would like to use a tidyverse solution. Thanks!

```
Make   Model     Value   
Ford   Focus     2,300
Chevy  NA        15
Toyota NA        245
Honda  NA        NA
Nissan NA        NA
```

Comment: I do not think you can tell R that `Focus` belongs to a different column than `Nissan`. Not unless you've got a lookup-table with car brands somewhere..

Comment: @Wimpel that's kinda what I assumed

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like (this relies on complete data `Make` data):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

make <- c("Ford", "Chevy", "Toyota", "Honda", "Nissan")

df |>
  mutate(id = cumsum(value %in% make),
         name = case_when(value %in% make ~ "Make",
                          grepl("\\d", value) ~ "Value",
                          T ~ "Model"))|>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id) |>
  select(-id)
```

**Output**

```
  Make   Model Value
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1 Ford   Focus 2,300
2 Chevy  NA    15   
3 Toyota NA    245  
4 Honda  NA    NA   
5 Nissan NA    NA
```